# Problem in moving communities from Sandbox to Production--- getting validation errors

Tags: community, deployment

I am trying to move two communities, one Lightning commmunity(Customer Service template) and the other one salesforce tabs + visualforce.

Getting the following validation errors when I try to deploy it from sandbox to production via change sets:

```
 Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following 
 feature and its associated permissions: Networks

 Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following 
 feature and its associated permissions: Moderation Rules

 Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following 
 feature and its associated permissions: User Criteria

 Missing feature, Details: Installing this package requires the following 
 feature and its associated permissions: Keyword Lists
```

Now these errors are very general and i have no idea what I could be missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is Communities enabled in the destination Org?

Comment: Thanks for replying back. No its not enabled. It asks me to choose a domain name first. Does it need to be the same domain name as sandbox or I can give it some other name?

Comment: Typically choosing a domain name depends on availability and choice of Business/IT teams. Check [Enable Salesforce Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=5) for details. This [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5) though mentions to keep the name same as sandbox to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments that Community is not enabled in your Production Org, you will not able to deploy your Community in that case. The pre-requisite for a Community deployment either using Change Set or Metadata API is that you will first need to [Enable Salesforce Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=5) in Production/destination org.

As for your question on domain name, while it typically depends on the Business/IT Teams (usually that's how we would come to choose a community domain name), but the [Tips and Considerations section](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5) of the help article on deployment using metadata API mentions that it should be same as that of sandbox and also mentions enabling the communities as pre-requisite.

> Before migrating data to another org, [enable Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=5) in the destination org and enter the same domain name that you used in your sandbox org to avoid getting an error.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand that domain name should be the same. However, we no longer like that domain name and want to change it in production. So I added a new domain name in production. Do I have to create sites in production as well?

Comment: That should be all. You don’t really need to create a site for the purpose of communities.